# Screen shot drop down menu with snipping tool

Tags: screenshot, snipping

Using the Windows snipping tool, it is not possible (or is it?) to get a screenshot of a drop down menu.  As soon as you select "New" in the snipping tool's toolbar, then the drop down menu disappears.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I can't do this with the Snipping Tool, but I've done it with [GreenShot](https://getgreenshot.org).

Comment: Might be a good scenario for Alt+Print Scrn (copies active window to clipboard)

Comment: Richard gave a nice answer - I always wondered what that Delay was about!

Comment: Use time delay or use Ctrl + PrntScrn [Ref: How to capture the right-click menu or any menu?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/take-screenshot-windows-different-ways-prnt-scrn/#m3)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Whenever I've needed to do this, I set a delay on the snipping tool - usually between 3 and 5 seconds.

This gives me enough time to click on "New" and then open the drop-down menu before the screenshot is taken.

Comment: For the replacement tool snip and sketch the delay is hidden under the arrow next to new

Answer (score 2):

The delay feature only works for the Windows 10+ version of the snipping because it wasn't introduced until then. For earlier versions, you need to use the cntrl-PrtScr option. Open up the Snipping Tool. If it's active to create a new snip, click cancel or hit the ESC key. Open up the desired menu and press cntl-PrtScr, this will reactivate the Snipping tool but leave the menu open. Then you can select what kind snip you want to make (free form, rectangular, window or full screen) and grab your screenshot.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Snipping Tool.
2. Press the **Esc** key.
3. On a desktop computer (or external) keyboard, press **Ctrl + PrtScr** (the **PrtScr** button is next to **F12**). On a laptop computer, press **Ctrl + Fn + End/PrtScr** (or the corresponding key sequence, depending on your model of laptop). This captures the entire screen, including the open menu.
4. Provided the default mode for snipping is **rectangular snip**, you can select the area of the menu immediately. If it is not or you are unsure, select the arrow next to the **New** button in the **Snipping Tool** window, choose **rectangular snip**, and then select the area of the screen capture that your want.

Answer (score 1):

What happened to you, happened to me, but here is the best, the oldest way of all: PrintScreen button (normally top/right area of an standard keyboard) I hope you still have it in your keyboard. Most new nb's keyboard don't have it. Most standard Desktop's keyboard still have it.
If so, when you press it, it got a screenshot of 1,2,3 as many monitors you have, a whole full screen, the you use Paint (or called Paintbrush) and you select what you want.
Now, if you don't have that type of keyboard, then you need a special software probably someone else mentioned already. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have an option of Delay Snip, set the timer to 4 second.
Once You Click New, the timer will be ON and you will have time to open the exact screen with the Drop down eventually the screen will freeze and you'll have to select the area to have your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you load Snip from the Windows Store, pressing PrntScn activates Snip. Snip will allow you to select a portion of the screen including any drop down menu

Answer (score -1):

easy way is to Share Your screen with  colleague and open the drop down tell him to take screenshot and send over mail

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).